# How to call java method in JSTL

Tags: java, jsp, jstl, jsp-tags

i declared these method in JSP as follows:

```
<%!
String getAmPm(Date d){
String am_pm = "AM";
String hour = String.valueOf(d.getHours());
if (hour.length() == 1) {
hour = "0" + hour;
    }
String hr_ampm = HarfDate.getHourAmPm(hour);
hour = hr_ampm.split(",")[0];
am_pm = hr_ampm.split(",")[1];
return am_pm;
}
%>
```

the above method takes a date object and return AM or PM according to the exact time of the date applied, if we use scriptlet we will call it as follows:

```
if(getAmPm(((PublishedExamsVO)publishedExams[i]).getTo()).equals("AM"))
```

Note:`(PublishedExamsVO)publishedExams[i]).getTo()` returns date object

i want to call these method using JSTL, any idea about doing that? i i have seen `fmt:formatDate` but i think that it won't rescue me

Comment: It's hard to answer without knowing what the above code is supposed to do.

Answer (score 0):

You're trying to put too much logic in the view, instead of using Java and encapsulation to provide behavior to the view. Simply add the following method to your PublishedExamsVO class, and use it from your view:

```
public boolean isMorning() {
    ...
}
```

...

```
<c:if test="${publishedExams.morning}">
    ...
</c:if>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can get the AM/PM indicator with `fmt:formatDate` using the format `"a"`:

```
<fmt:formaDate pattern="a" value="${yourDateHere}" />
```

To test the return value, you have to assign it first to a variable:

```
<c:set var="period">
   <fmt:formaDate pattern="a" value="${yourDateHere}" />
</c:set>
<c:if test="${period eq 'AM'}">xxxx</c:set>
```

Comment: and how to test the return value of these function?

Answer (score 0):

If you need some reusable piece of code for your JSPs consider functions instead of scriptlets. Checkout this [blog post](http://www.noppanit.com/how-to-create-a-custom-function-for-jstl/) as a quick example.